# How to implement sound and vibration together in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, haptic-feedback

Annotating onTapGesture activates sound. But the vibration doesn't work. How to implement sound and vibration together?

Why does this problem occur?

```
let feedback = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .soft)

func activeNum() {
    playSound(sound: "casino-chips", type: "mp3")
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            LogoView()
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                self.activeNum()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
//                        .onTapGesture {
//                            feedback.impactOccurred()
//                        }
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Button` action, call both `activeNum()` and `impactOccured()` rather than trying to put the latter in a separate `onTapGesture`:

```
Button(action: {
 self.activeNum()
 feedback.impactOccurred()
}
```

Comment: OMG I should have written it in action, but I forgot. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Feel free to accept/upvote